# How can bash be used to pipe stdout to a script AND write to terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to pipe the output of a job to a script to read in that stdout lines and complete actions and display the output on the terminal.

Right now, I have this..

```
ls | ./script.sh
```

This allows my script to be run on the output, but does not display the result of ls on the terminal.

I have tried this:

```
ls | tee ./script.sh
```

but this *overwrites the contents* of script.sh with the output from ls.

How can I show the output of "ls" on my terminal, and run the contents on script.sh over that input?  Here is an example of what my script.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
  do
    echo line input
  done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
 ls | tee /dev/tty | ./script.sh
```

or, if you want to use exactly what stdout was before the piping, you can do
something like:

```
{ ls | tee /dev/fd/3 | ./script.sh ; } 3>&1 #(3 is an semi-arbirtrary choice of fd)
```

Comment: `/dev/tty` is optional in `ls | tee /dev/tty | ./script.sh`, right?

Comment: @codeforester It's not optional. Without it, the output (=copied input=ls's output) would go just to the script. With it, it goes to the controlling terminal and to the script.